# A question about the system recommendation tag

Tags: support

I recently posted a question [What are the major differences between AD&D 1st Edition & AD&D 2nd Edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22548/what-are-the-major-differences-between-add-1st-edition-add-2nd-edition) and I was wondering if this question meets the requirements for the system-recommendation tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

system-recommendation is for choosing a game to fulfill a set of requirements.

Your question is about those two systems in particular, so it's fine tagged as it is.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that